# drawer at bottom of screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I want a memories app. In this app you can click a memory and it opens a drawer on the bottom that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lWeb.png I think this makes sense from a ui standpoint as opening the drawer from the side would waste screen real estate unless you are in landscape mode, but the moduratie of people aren't.

I have tried searching on google I did find:

```
return Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
   endDrawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(child: Text("right drawer"))
```

however in dartpad this has not worked because endDrawer is not defined bottomDrawer doesent work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**showModalBottomSheet** should work for what you're trying to do. It's worked for me in the past.

Here is a code snippet I used for my past To Do List project that included **showModalBottomSheet**:

```
class TasksScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(),
            );
```

The code snippet above activates the modal bottom sheet to slide up from the bottom of the app after clicking a floating action button.

Picture of how it looks in my app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p41J8.jpg

Flutter Docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html